# call recursive function in asp.net using json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm new to json and stuff .. 
I'm trying to bind a recursive table to a nested  ul  element .
I decided to bind parent Item into a  li  element , so when user click on the item , i want to load its children .
it works for the first bunch of children , but when i want to load inner level , although it goes through my method and fetch the appropriate data , still shows current level . and when i checked i found out it calls the inner method twice ...

That's the method i'm calling , first time with ID=0 and after that with currentParentID :

```
 public static IEnumerable GetItemsByParentID(int pID)
 { return from ctg in _ctx.Categories where ctg.CategoryParentID == pID select ctg; }
```

MyTreeview.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default2.aspx/GetItemsByParentID",
    data: "{'pID':'0'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#MyContainer').setTemplateURL ('MyCtg.htm',null, { filter_data: false });
        $('#MyContainer').processTemplate(msg);
    }
});
});

function LoadChildren(value) {

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default2.aspx/GetItemsByParentID",
    data: "{'pID':'"+value+"'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#child'+value).setTemplateURL('MyCtg.htm',null, { filter_data: false });
        $('#child' + value).processTemplate(msg);
    }
});

}



MyCtg.htm: 
<ul>
{#foreach $T.d as post}
<li  onclick="LoadChildren({$T.post.CategoryID})">
    {$T.post.CategoryName} 
    <ol id="child{$T.post.CategoryID}"></ol>
</li>
{#/for}
```

```
Default.aspx :  <div id="MyContainer"> </div>
```

what am i doing wrong here ?!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the onclick the event will bubble up and call the parent method too, so what you need to do is to stop the propagation by using :

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: What parent method will it call?

Comment: As I understand, you have <li>(parent) and inside more <li>(child) and both respond to the click if you click on a child, so you get the child content overwritten.